# How to reference another project from an F# project?

Tags: f#

I have two F# projects in a solution. I added a reference of project1 to project2. When I try to use modules from project1 I get

> Error     The type referenced through 'xxx' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'yyy'.

Error tells that reference of a dll which is used by project1 should be added to project2. With C# it works only by adding a reference to the other project. Is there something extra we should do in order to avoid adding those dlls to every project we use references?

Comment: *"With C# it works only by adding a reference to the other project."* I'm fairly certain that that statement is false. Also in C#, you'll need to add a transitive reference if you want to *use* a type with said transitive dependency. Therefore, in both C# and F#, the solution is to add the dependency to the library where you want to use the functionality, just as the error message states.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Are you suggesting that I should reference dlls that other project uses, in second project, in c#? I am not only sure but also looking right at it. I only referenced the c# project. And that project uses dlls which I don't have references of in the second project.

Comment: In C#, this requirement only 'triggers' when you start using one of the types that have a transitive dependency. Just adding a reference in itself will not cause the error to occur, because the compiler will not need the transitive dependency until the 'top' of the transitive chain is used. Likewise, at run-time, the transitively referenced assembly will stay unloaded until needed.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I believe we are talking about different things. Main dll of project only requires dependency dlls to be in the same hierarchical relative paths. You assume that I tried it with C# after F# problem. It is actually the other way around. I am porting my working C# project to F#. Thus, original solution has no problem using only referrnces of other projects.

Comment: @ozgur First, post the *actual* error message. Second, if you write a test project in C# that references your data layer library you don't need to add a reference to System.Data. If you try to use an ADO.NET class though, you do. F# works the same.